# android focusSearch does not return Spinner

Tags: android, focus, spinner

I have created an application which contains a form having multiple edittexts and spinners.

On Softkeyboard pop up I have created  a 'next' button which keeps shifting focus to the next widget in the form.
I have used the focusSearch() for the same with 'View.FOCUS_DOWN' as the direction.
However the focusSearch() method never returns the Spinner object. It always takes me to the next focusable EditText. I have observed similar pattern with the 'Next" action button present on the softkeyboard.
Is there a way to bring focus to the Spinner?

Comment: I guess that spinners alike radio buttons do not get focus as the softkeyboard has no role in making selection. So in a form the user may enter all the values in edittexts navigating using the next button and select values for spinners by touch. However when in Landscape orientation ,in fullscreen editing view the softkeyboard appears over the form and only the editable text is displayed. In this case the user might have to scroll all the way up the form to make selection for spinners once all the edit fields have been entered with required values.Can there be any workaround for this?